# SQL - If two records have same value in two columns, add third column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with these values:

```
Col1  | Col2    | Col3 |  
one   | two     |  3   |  
four  | five    |  6   |  
four  | seven   |  8   |  
four  | seven   |  9   |
```

I want to make a query that returns a row for every record in which Col1 and Col2 are both different than in every other record, but if they are both the same in two records, the result should be one single row with those values in Col1 and Col2 and their Col3 sum in the third column. The result should be:

```
Col1  | Col2   | ColNew |  
one   | two    |  3     |  
four  | five   |  6     |  
four  | seven  | 17     |
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is called an aggregation query and uses `group by`.  This is very basic SQL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!  Then you don't need any of those messy `&nbsp;` tags, either!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` on the columns you want to "group by" (1 and 2 in your case). Then use `SUM` on the column you want to "sum" (3 in your case).

```
select a.col1, a.col2, sum(a.col3) as colNew
from test as a
group by a.col1, a.col2;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/070a3/4

Answer (score 4):

Just a really simple, plain `GROUP BY` and a `SUM` will do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    Col1, Col2, ColNew = SUM(Col3)
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY 
    Col1, Col2
```